# Why the file session returning null when trying to test on the browser?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I can't figure out for the life of me why `null` is being returned when trying to do a file upload.  The JS is logging the content correctly in terms of the file but for some reason, my backend can't recognize it.

[This is what's being logged in the console:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq2V3.png)

When testing on Postman, I could see the file content perfectly fine via `dd($request->file('file'));` but on the browser, it dumps `null`.

To fix this, I've tried wrapping that `dd($request->file('file'));` in an `if()` but this returns `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null` error in the network tab when testing on the browser:

```
if($request->hasFile('file')) {
    dd($request->file('file'));
}
```

So in conclusion, when testing on the browser without the `if()` - the `dd();` dumps `null` and with the `if()` - the `dd();` returns `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null` error and in Postman, everything works fine.  How can I fix it so that it works in the browser?

Controller code:

```
public function support(Request $request)
{
      dd($request->file('image')); // returns null when testing on the browser

      if($request->hasFile('image')) { 
         dd($request->file('image')); // returns Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null error
      }
}
```

React code:

```
const [fileContent, setFileContent] = useState(null);

// Create a reference to the hidden file input element
const hiddenFileInput = React.useRef(null);

const handleClick = () => {
    // Programmatically click the hidden file input element
    // when the Button component is clicked
    hiddenFileInput.current.click();
};

// Call a function (passed as a prop from the parent component)
// to handle the user-selected file
const handleChange = (event) => {
    setFileContent(event.target.files[0]);
};

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let data = {
        'file'  : fileContent
    };

    console.log(data); // Logging correctly

    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json'
    }

    axios.post('http://localhost/api/support', data, {headers})
        .then(resp => {
            console.log(resp);
        }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
};

    return(
        <form method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="contact-form-group">
            <label htmlFor="file"/>
            <input type="file" id="real-file" hidden="hidden" ref={hiddenFileInput} name="file" onChange={handleChange} />
            <button type="button" id="custom-button" onClick={handleClick}>Choose File</button>
         </div>
       </form>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

This example builds a FormData instance containing values for fields named "username", "accountnum", "userfile" and "webmasterfile", then uses the XMLHttpRequest method send() to send the form's data. The field "webmasterfile" is a Blob.

[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('File', fileContent);
  const headers = {
      "Accept": 'application/json'
  }

  axios.post('http://localhost/api/support', formData, {headers})
      .then(resp => {
          console.log(resp);
      }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
  });
};
```

Comment: But what If I want to add other fields in the post request?  I can't just send formData alone

Comment: also, fileContent cannot be used in that append with Blob (File)